# C# and Awesomium - multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, awesomium

I want to use multiple instances of Awesomium(without actully showing/printing them) to visit certain websites at the same time but don't know where to start.
I've made this with WebBrowser control but it turned out it's a very bad idea and I've decided to switch to Awesomium.

Thank you in advance!

I will add some example code, hopefully it will show what I exactly need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Create new view/control/instance here
    });
    th.Start();
 }
```

I've tried to create WebView there but I get Memory corrupt error.

Comment: What have you tried, as it stands your not really providing specifics into your issue mostly just generality.

Comment: Sorry but not being specific in details. I just don't know where to start. I tried to find something in the documentation but I didn't. I just need to know where to start, example or something...

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, Awesomium does not support multiple threads, so getting an error is normal.
You can create multiple Awesomiums component WebControl on same thread(easiest one is UI thread - otherwise you need to provide "screen" refresh code yourself).

Comment: Will they run simultaneously and how I can accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
        private void newbrowser()
    {
        Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl browser =
                                    new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
            browser = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
            browser.Paint += browser_Paint;
            browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
            browser.Name = "webControl";
            browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);
            browser.Source = new System.Uri("http://checkip.dyndns.com/", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            browser.TabIndex = 0;

    }
```

and then

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread newThread;
        newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(newbrowser);
        newThread.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user1410644
Awesomium does not support multiple threads as told in documents ..
after initialize you can create multiple webviews they will do the job and will work

start for loop then

```
            WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(folder + "\\b" + i, prefs);
                            WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080, session, WebViewType.Offscreen);
                            view.LoadingFrameComplete += (se, ev) =>
                            {
                                if (ev.IsMainFrame)
                                {
                                    var bitmapSurface = (BitmapSurface)((WebView)se).Surface;
                                    var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(((WebView)se).Width, ((WebView)se).Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
                                    writeableBitmap.Lock();
                                    bitmapSurface.CopyTo(writeableBitmap.BackBuffer, bitmapSurface.RowSpan, 4, false, false);
                                    writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, ((WebView)se).Width, ((WebView)se).Height));
                                    writeableBitmap.Unlock();
                                    var image = new Image();
                                    image.Source = writeableBitmap;
                                    screenShot.Source = writeableBitmap;
                                }
                            };
                        view.Source = "http://www.google.com".ToUri();
```

somthing like this does the trick i think